# Cannot implicitely convert a Custom type to IDisposable Error

Tags: c#, exception, types, idisposable

I've got this piece of code:

```
try
{
    using(conn)
    {
         conn.UpdateScheduledTaskGuid(taskID, taskGUID);            
    }
}
```

On the **conn** variable I'm getting the error "**Cannot implicitly convert type DataProvider to System.IDisposable**"

DataProvider is a custom class that someone created in this project I'm working in which is the type for the conn variable above.

I guess I need to have DataProvider implement IDisposable but I am not sure if that's really the problem here or not and if I do have to implement it, what unmanaged resources is it having a problem with that requires me to add IDisposable?

Here's the DataProvider class:[DataProvider.txt](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6FDE5kMwYTlZjkzYWE0NTItMGY2NS00ZTlkLWE4MTAtMWM2MTliMTAxOTcy&hl=en_US&authkey=CKvUnfoD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataProvider` must indeed implement `IDisposable`, because it owns a `IDbConnection`, which it must properly dispose of.

Comment: Thanks. So..I've never implemented an IDisposal.  I just implemented the interface and I assume in my Dispose() method I need to do a this.Dispose(); which means the current DataProvider instance is disposed of?

Comment: so I'm assuming after I implement IDisposal on my Data Provider class, then the dispose method might be         public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose();
        }  (this is unecessary as it knows it's talking about the current instance of this class)

Comment: @Coffee, no, if you call `this.Dispose()` inside `Dispose()`, you will have infinite recursion.  Rather, you should dispose of the database connection in `DataProvider.Dispose`.  Also look at the link in Rick's comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463408/cannot-implicitely-convert-a-custom-type-to-idisposable-error/6463434#6463434).

Answer (score 4):

From [the MSDN page about the using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

```
Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.
```

and

> All such types must implement the
> IDisposable interface.

So yes, you will need to have your DataProvider implement IDisposable to use it as you are in a using block.

Comment: Note that implementing `IDisposable` is a little tricky so follow the standard pattern: [Implementing Finalize and Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The "using" keyword is just a helpful way of writing exception-safe code that will call Dispose() when the variable goes out of scope. If you're not going to call Dispose(), it's not useful. That function is declared by the IDisposable interface.

If you don't have unmanaged resources, you shouldn't be using "using" on it, anyway.

A good description of this is here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/using_and_IDisposable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to use the 'using' statement the object needs to implement IDisposable.  I looked through a bit of that code and I didn't see any unmanaged code (although I could be mistaken since there is a ton of code there).